# Visual Studio 2012 include files and folders in project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I made a bunch of changes to a folder. I

- checked the whole folder out from TFS 2012 (removes read-only flag)
- then copied my changes (many files in many different folders) to the working copy, overwritting existing files
- tried to include all new files into the project

But I failed on the last step. For "Include in project" I need to select the target files oder folders, but this is no option, too many files in too many folders. Is there some way to do it efficiently, without going through every folder and looking for new files manually?

Comment: Are you just trying to add the new files to TFS, or are you also trying to add them to your visual studio projects (.csproj etc)?

Comment: I am trying to add them to my visual studio project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did now: I

- removed all files and folders in my project
- copied the new files and folders to their target location
- enable "Show all files" in the Solution Explorer
- include the copied files and folders

Now I have the correct files and folders in my solution, BUT I lost my version history on them (ok, they were mostly images with no edits on them).

Comment: I will leave this question open, maybe someone else find a solution that also saves the version history.