# Restore deleted workspace in TFS to retrieve pending edits

Tags: version-control, disaster-recovery

I had edits on my local machine which had it's own workspace. I was given a new machine and I have setup a new workspace with my new machine. By mistake I deleted my old workspace while there were still pending edits associated with it. Now I lost all my pending edits. Is there a way to retrieve all my lost pending edits.

Please note that I still have access to my old machine. If I'm able to retrieve all my lost pending edits I can bring those files to my new machine and check-in those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

1. On your new machine use "Get Specific Version" to get the same source changeset (the last changeset you retrieved to your previous machine). Set it up as a Local Workspace, that way Visual Studio will detect changed files automatically as "Checked Out".
2. From your old machine zip up all the files
3. Extract all the files over the workspace on your new machine.
4. Wait for the local workspace to be consolidated (give Visual Studio some time to figure out which files have changed)
5. Use ["Include in project"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186646/736079) to add any files that you added on your previous machine.
6. Use "Get Latest Version", fix any merge conflicts, Build everything, Run your unit tests
7. Check in your code.

This will not detect deleted files, but modified/added files should be detected/added. You'll have to compare the list of file sin both systems to ensure all deletes are handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. The solution looks promising but the problem is I don't have the changeset details that I had in my old machine. Is there a way to come around this?

Comment: No, I don't think there is.